# Is there a quicker way to filter a Pandas data frame based on the number of recurring values?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am using the following function;

```py
 df['i'] = df.groupby(['i']).filter(lambda i: len(i) > 500)
```

This works as intended, tested on other data frames, except when dealing with large quantities of groups. I am trying to use this with around 50,000 groups and have thus far not seen my program process this line.
The longest I have let the program run is a bit under 48 hours.

Edit: The method works fine for large groups assuming the lambda function does not remove all the groups. decreasing the minimum length a group can be to 250 allowed the program to execute within 30 seconds.

Comment: can you run df.groupby(['i']).filter(lambda i: len(i) > 500)['i'].unique() and see it can return the result quick enough? You can filter against that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for parallel computing if your processor has multiple cores...

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
    return pandas.concat(ret_list)
```

this does not cover every situation that you put a function on but will cover yours.

Comment: Just trying to make sure I am implementing your proposed solution correctly, dfGrouped is the groupby class and func is the lambda function?

Edited: nevermind, I figured it out. I would have liked for the process to be vectorized but this should do fine.